# Email unique in DB per Client

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, php-7.1

I am using laravel 5.4 with couchbase with php 7.1

In our system, one can create new users. Till now, the email field had to be unique to the database users-table, no problem, we used this in our request

```
'email'        => 'required|email|unique:users,email,NULL,user_id,datetime_deleted,NULL',
```

This was working fine.
Now, we have a new request to our application that the email of an user has to be unique not to the whole user-table, but to one client, so we can have several times the same email address, but with differences in the 'client_id' field in the document.

How can i put this in my Request-Class?

Comment: Check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44658475/7894379). Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

For laravel 5.3 and above
You can add additional where clause for unique validation as below

```
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})
```

don't forget to mention
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

OR Try
For laravel 5.2

While insert

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email,NULL,id,user_id,'.Auth::user()->id,
```

While update

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email,{id of object to edit},id,user_id,'.Auth::user()->id,
```

In the rule above, only rows with an user_id of Auth::id() would be included in the unique check.